# What does this means when describes a person's eyes/gaze looking at you ?焦点の合わない瞳で、ぼやーっと見た。

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**I'm having troubles with this expression, appreciates if someone can make this clear.**

**焦点の合わない瞳で、ぼやーっと見た。**

My guess : "..looking at me with absentmindedly eyes."

or

"...looking at me vaguely with distracted looks"

Comment: Can you explain where you're having trouble with the expression? Both of your translations are pretty similar in meaning.

Comment: 焦点の合わない瞳で  this part confused me , i can't imagine such eyes and can only guess its meaning.

Comment: Your old habit is showing in your new life, casual reader.

Comment: 焦点の合わない瞳 is a bit poetic and not uncommon phrase that implies you are not paying attention in details. It doesn't mean optically unfocused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

焦点が合う is simply "(someone's eyes) being in focus", so it should be clear that this should mean "(Someone) gazed absentmindedly with unfocused eyes".